# How to make a fixed side navigation bar move to the right side on html/css?

Tags: html, css

Here's my css code:

```
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 160px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

I have tried messing around with right and lift as well as padding on left and right sides but everything I've tried has kept the sidebar stuck to the left side. How can I make it move to the right side? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `.sidenav` class property `left` to `right`:

```
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 160px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

What `left: 0` means is anchor the div to the relative container 0 pixels from the left side, changing it to `right: 0` tells the css it to anchor it 0 pixels from the right side.

Comment: I have to wait 9 mins for some reason, but for sure will

Comment: Great, happy coding my friend!